# minimum polynomial definition

Tags: definition, minimal-polynomials

I was wondering if anyone could define the term "$m(x)$ is a minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$".

I thought it means $m(x)$ is a monic polynomial in $K$ such that $m(\alpha)=0$?

Comment: You need to add "... of minimum degree".

Comment: What does this mean ?

Comment: It means that if anyone finds another polynomial $p\in K[x]$ such that $p(\alpha)=0$, then the degree of $p$ is greater than or equal to the degree of $m$. Using Euclidean division, more can be said. In fact, this condition would imply that $m$ divides $p$. Proof: Write $p=mq+r$, with $deg(r)<deg(m)$. Then $0=p(\alpha)=m(\alpha)q(\alpha)+r(\alpha)=r(\alpha)$. This can only happen if $r$ is the zero polynomial because otherwise $r$, divided by its leading coefficient would produce a monic polynomial that has $\alpha$ as a root and has yet smaller degree than $m$.

Comment: So the definition should be $m(x)$ is a monic polynomial of minimum degree in $K$ such that $m(\alpha)=0$ then $m(x)$ is a minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clearly, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that $p(\alpha)=0$, then any polynomial $f(x)$ with $p|f$ has $f(\alpha)$ too. So, there are lots of polynomials that kills $\alpha$. However, if we ask the polynomial to be monic and of the smallest possible order (such that it still kills $\alpha$!), then there is only one (exercise), which is called the minimal polynomial. In this point of view, you can feel that a minimal polynomial is a very canonical object that relates to your element $\alpha$.

When $\alpha$ is in the base field, $x-\alpha$ is **the** minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ since it kills $\alpha$ directly. However, when $\alpha$ is not in the base field, **any** polynomials of order 1 cannot kill $\alpha$ (easy exercise). Thus the degree of **the** minimal polynomial somehow "measures" how far $\alpha$ is from the base field. The further $\alpha$ stays away from the base field, the higher the order should be. We thus define the degree of $\alpha$ to be the order of **the** minimal polynomial.

Any algebraic number stays "finitely far away" from $\mathbb{Q}$, while the others (transcendentals like $e$ or $\pi$) stays "infinitely far away"!

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer!.